# Nameservers on ubuntu 14.04 server with VestaCP

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, ubuntu-14.04, nameserver

I have a pretty annoying nameserver problem on this ubuntu server of mine... I tried altering resolv.conf, i tried altering network/interfaces, i tried altering it trough the control panel, i just don't seem to get how to do it...

Do you guys know what could it be the answer if not those in those files?

I'm having problem even on troubleshooting this... I'm now totally lost.

additional info:

ping 8.8.8.8 - WORKS

ping ;myipadress; - WORKS

ping www.google.com - DON'T WORK

ping ;myDomainName; - WORKS (without the "www.")
full content of /etc/resolv.conf

```
search maisideiasdigital.com.br
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

important part of content of /etc/network/interfaces

```
iface venet0:0 inet static
        address 93.188.165.192
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        dns-search google.com
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Result of curl www.google.com or dig www.google.com: not responding at all, just finishes at: could not resolve host: www.google.com

EDIT: I'm sorry, I'm a little bit newbie to those heavier server managements...

Comment: `ping <yourdomain>` may be working because it might be in your /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

1. **It could be that DNS is blocked by a firewall.**

Try `host www.google.com 8.8.8.8` so that you are directly querying Googles DNS servers. If you can ping 8.8.8.8, but that command fails I would look at iptables or any other firewall you may have.

2. **If the above works and you are convinced nothing is being blocked, look at /etc/nsswitch.conf which defines how host names are resolved.**

---

**Example nsswitch.conf entries from my systems that work**

Ubuntu 16.10:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve dns
```

Ubuntu 16.04:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

And Ubuntu CentOS 7:

```
hosts:      files dns myhostname
```